# Comment JS is not working in VF page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

We have some JS functions inside a `<script></script>` tag in a VF page. Something strange happens. We commented a piece of js code deprecated but the code seems not commented at all.

For Example when we saved the error "Label.ErrorLoadingEvents does not exist" appears.

I don't understand what is happening and why this commented code seems not commented. Someone help me please.

Below you find the piece of code:

```
vm.loadEvents = function() {
                var owner = vm.workOrder==null ? null : vm.workOrder.OwnerId;
                /*
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.InspectorAgendaController.GetInspectorEvents}', owner, function(results, event) {
                    if(event.statusCode==200) {
                        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
                            var calendarEvent = vm.mapSFtoJS(results[i]);
                            vm.events.push(calendarEvent);
                        }
                        vm.calendarReady = true;
                        $scope.$apply();
                    } else {
                        vm.showErrorMessage("{!$Label.ErrorLoadingEvents}");
                        vm.showErrorMessage("ErrorLoadingEvents");
                    }
                });*/

            };
            vm.loadEvents();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{!` expressions get evaluated by VF even if you commented the JS code. That means that this line

`{!$RemoteAction.InspectorAgendaController.GetInspectorEvents}`

Is getting evaluated regardless. You have to remove the `{!` (just remove the `!`) so VF no longer identifies that as an expression to evaluate and safely ignores it.